# iOS App Compatible with iPhone and iPod Touch but not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I just got my Universal iOS app approved by Apple and In compatibility its showing : **Compatibility: Requires iOS 8.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone and iPod touch.**

Its weird that why its not showing iPads ?

and Its also showing : **This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad** just below the "view in iTunes".

I have cross checked that Devices settings are Universal under Target Deployment Info and Target Device family is set as 1,2 for Pods, Project and Target. Screenshots are also properly showing on iTunes of both iPhone and iPad.

Basically I want it to be working on iPads too.

Don't know which step I am missing.

Please share your help regarding this concern. Looking forward to hear positive answers.

Thanks in Advance !